# How to prevent the ZStack lower level View from reacting?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I wrote the following code using ZStack.
This is the bottom sheet implemented using ZStack.

I want the grayed-out upper layer View to prevent the lower layer View's button from responding.
But the button of the lower layer View respond.

This makes it impossible to reproduce the modal bottom sheet movement.

How can I prevent the lower level View from responding when the upper level View is out?

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var isShow = false

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Button(
        "Show Sheet",
        action: {
          withAnimation {
            self.isShow.toggle()
          }
        }
      )
      .zIndex(0)

      BottomSheet(
        isShow: self.$isShow,
        content: {
          VStack {
            Text("A")
            Text("B")
            Text("C")
          }
          .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity
          )
          .background(Color(.yellow))
        }
      )
      .zIndex(1)
    }
  }
}

struct ScrimView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {}.frame(
      maxWidth: .infinity,
      maxHeight: .infinity,
      alignment: .bottom
    )
    .background(
      Color(.gray)
    )
  }
}

struct BottomSheet<Content: View>: View {
  private let content: () -> Content
  @Binding var isShow: Bool

  init(
    isShow: Binding<Bool>,
    content: @escaping () -> Content
  ) {
    self._isShow = isShow
    self.content = content
  }

  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
      ScrimView().zIndex(
        0
      )
      .opacity(
        self.isShow ? 0.5 : 0
      )

      VStack {
        Button(
          "X",
          action: {
            withAnimation {
              self.isShow = false
            }
          }
        )
        self.content()
      }
      .zIndex(1)
      .background(Color(.white))
      .cornerRadius(10)
      .offset(x: 0, y: self.isShow ? 0 : 500)
    }
  }
}
```

main:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FooApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to use the bottom sheet in various views.
So, it doesn't make sense to turn off only the button in this case.

Comment: can you simply disable the lower view when the overlay is shown?

Comment: I want to use the bottom sheet in various views. 
So, it doesn't make sense to turn off only the button in this case.

Comment: In that case, you should look into creating your own [ViewModifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 methods:

#### Method #1

Doesn't visually change, just ignores presses on the button.

```
Button("Show Sheet") {
    withAnimation {
        self.isShow.toggle()
    }
)
.allowsHitTesting(!isShow)
```

#### Method #2

Visually disables the button (looks gray).

```
Button("Show Sheet") {
    withAnimation {
        self.isShow.toggle()
    }
)
.disabled(isShow)
```

Comment: The method #1 make doesn't visually change. I prefer it.

Comment: Personally, I think if a button is disabled it should look disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You could just disable the button when showing the other views:

```swift
ZStack {
      Button(
        "Show Sheet",
        action: {
          withAnimation {
            self.isShow.toggle()
          }
        }
      )
      .zIndex(0)
      .disabled(isShow)
```

Comment: It's `disabled`, not `isDisabled `

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use the bottom sheet in various views. 
So, it doesn't make sense to turn off only the button in this case.

Comment: Ah, so what you mean is that we should just push all the lower level Views into one View. and use isDisabled.

Comment: I mean just disable the button, The modifier is only attached to the button, so that is what is disabled or enabled.